# Make default Android orange as focused,pressed,selected state of a custom buttom

Tags: android

I have a custom button, but for the focused,pressed,selected state I wanna have the default Android orange selected state rather than make new custom images for those states.

How am I able to achieve that? What should I write on the selector for those states?

Comment: you need to copy the android orange default image from android res folder and paste into your project and add the same in drawable state list background of button

Comment: can you give me the exact path for the folder?

Comment: path is android-sdk_windows\platforms\android-2.1\data\res\drawable-hdpi\btn_default_pressed .

Comment: cool, got it. Any idea how to make those buttons cover the normal state of my custom button,instead of replacing it with a plain orange block?

Comment: open your custom button image in Photoshop ,edit it and add a orange gradient over it. It will show when user selects the button, instead show the default image

Comment: so the bottom line is, everything has to be done manually ^^ alright thanks anyway

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am sure you want to implement that default orange color image inside your custom selector file, if this is the case then you can know the name of all the in-built drawable files used by system, from here you can know: [Android Drawables](http://androiddrawableexplorer.appspot.com/)

Some of button default images names are:

1. btn_default_pressed.9
2. btn_default_selected.9
3. btn_default_small_pressed.9
4. btn_default_small_selected.9

so now copy the 9-patch images inside the `res/drawable` folder and use it wherever you want.

Comment: the question is, where can I find them? So I can copy them to my drawable

Comment: @hectichavana ok fine, and also available on above link.

Answer (score 4):

Check this code it'll give you a lead about how to change the colors for each state.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item android:state_pressed="true" >
    <shape>
        <gradient
            android:startColor="#F5B800"
            android:endColor="#F5B800"
            android:angle="270" />
        <stroke
            android:width="1dp"
            android:color="#ffcc00" />
        <corners
            android:radius="1dp" />
        <padding
            android:left="10dp"
            android:top="10dp"
            android:right="10dp"
            android:bottom="10dp" />
    </shape>
</item>

<item android:state_focused="true" >
    <shape>
        <gradient
            android:endColor="#F5B800"
            android:startColor="#F5B800"
            android:angle="270" />
        <stroke
            android:width="1dp"
            android:color="#ffcc00" />
        <corners
            android:radius="1dp" />
        <padding
            android:left="10dp"
            android:top="10dp"
            android:right="10dp"
            android:bottom="10dp" />
    </shape>
</item>

<item>        
    <shape>
        <gradient
            android:endColor="#ff9900"
            android:startColor="#ffcc00"
            android:angle="270" />
        <stroke
            android:width="1dp"
            android:color="#ffcc00" />
        <corners
            android:radius="1dp" />
        <padding
            android:left="10dp"
            android:top="10dp"
            android:right="10dp"
            android:bottom="10dp" />
    </shape>
</item>
</selector>
```

Comment: okay I've tried. but when I put this for example <item android:state_focused="true" android:drawable="@drawable/share_button"> the orange shape is ignored otherwise I only see an orange block covering my normal button

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried not mentioning those states? i haven't tried but off the top of my head, i would say that if you donot mention a state, android should use the default values.

Comment: I am sure he just wants to access that orange color image.

Comment: ohhh no ... just ignore my answer, i just remembered that not mentioning states makes android unaware of those states so nothing happens. +1 to answer above by @Serdar Dogruyol.